# loopbackjs and passportConfigurator passport-facebook

Tags: loopbackjs

my loopbackjs (lb3) app allow login using facebook thanks to the passportConfigurator, passport-facebook and passport-facebook-token node modules.

It creates the users automatically as it should.

The issue is that i would like to add more parameters to be saved when user created after facebook login like UTM params.

i did't find the way to add more properties after facebook making the callback trick.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify your loopback version. As from the description its for lb3.
Moreover you can provide : 
profileFields: ['locale', 'name', 'email', ...[your desired fields]] 
in your PassPortConfigurator#configureProvider

Comment: How can i get my desired fields from the client side? how can i get the values from them from the header?